# Do while loop not allowing user control

Tags: excel, vba

This sub causes a cell to flash if the cell value contains today's date.

When run from the VBA editor I am able to open other userforms or use the project as normal.

When another sub calls the TransNotification sub I am unable to get the program to yield to the user. The sub has to be stopped from the VBA editor. I've placed DoEvents in several portions of the Do While loop with no success.

```
Public flash As Boolean
Sub TransNotification()
    Dim dateexists As Integer
    Dim rightnow As String

    rightnow = Format(Now(), "mm/dd/yy")
    dateexists = InStr(1, Sheet2.Range("R64").Value, rightnow)
    If dateexists <> 0 Then
        flash = True
    End If
    Sheet2.Unprotect
    Do While flash

        Sheet2.Range("R64").Interior.Color = RGB(39, 70, 32)
        WasteTime (1500)
        Sheet2.Range("R64").Interior.Color = RGB(50, 50, 50)
        WasteTime (1000)

        rightnow = Format(Now(), "mm/dd/yy")
        dateexists = InStr(1, Sheet2.Range("R64").Value, rightnow)
        If dateexists = 0 Then
            flash = False
        End If

    Loop
    Sheet2.Unprotect
    Sheet2.Range("R64").Interior.Color = RGB(50, 50, 50)
    Sheet2.Protect
End Sub

Sub WasteTime(Finish As Long)
    Dim NowTick As Long
    Dim EndTick As Long

    EndTick = GetTickCount + Finish

    Do
        NowTick = GetTickCount
        DoEvents
    Loop Until NowTick >= EndTick
End Sub
```

Comment: @David - Is there a reason you need the millisecond granularity of `GetTickCount`?  Instead of calling a Windows API function, I would suggest using `Timer` for your "pause" function.  I use: `Sub Pause(sec As Long): Dim startTime As Single: startTime = Timer: Do: DoEvents: Loop While startTime + sec > Timer: End Sub` ...also see [**How to make a cell flash in Excel and why I wouldn't do it!**](http://www.excelsupersite.com/how-to-make-a-cell-flash-in-excel/)

Comment: @ashleedawg I don't necessarily need millisecond resolution, however I had read that using Windows API allows you to pass functionality back to the user while the OS does its work. I figured this would be the better option. I'll check out the link. Thank you